# Как ограничить доступ к командам бота на заданое время

Tags: python, aiogram

Как ограничить выполнение команды на несколько секунд. Если команду вызвал один пользователь то доступ для этой команды для всех пользователей ограничен на время. А если кто то пробует вызвать команду то появляеться алерт что команду нельзя использовать столько то времени. На форуме нашел решение, но там не могу написать коментарий пока.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='weather')
async def command_weather(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(weather.get_weather())    
    last_time = datetime.now()
    
    delta = datetime.now() - last_time
    if delta.second > 30:
        await message.answer(weather.get_weather())    
    else:
        Тут алерт ('Извините 30 секунд ещё не прошло')
```

Там было так описано... но выходит если команду вызвать то команда все таки будет использована, а потом уже сработает условие...

```
import datetime

current_datetime = datetime.now()
```

IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось у aiogram уже есть готовое решение. Я просто не знал как правильно оно называется.

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/throtling_example.html

```
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled


 @dp.message_handler(commands='start')
    async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
        try:
            await dp.throttle('start', rate=10)
        except Throttled:
            await message.reply('Подождите 10 секунд. Нельзя часто использовать эту команду.')
        else:
            await message.reply("Команда выполнилась")
```

Comment: Такой вариант подходит если тот же человек использует команду. А я хочу чтобы Если одни ввел команду, то другой уже не сможет.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=30)


@dp.message_handler(commands='weather')
async def command_weather(message: types.Message):
    global last_time
    if (datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 30:
        await message.answer("Слишком часто")
        return

    await message.answer(weather.get_weather())
    last_time = datetime.now()
```

Пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD
Пример для инлайн кнопок

```
last_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=30)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Погода", callback_data="weather")))


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='weather')
async def command_weather(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global last_time
    if (datetime.now() - last_time).seconds < 30:
        await call.answer("Слишком часто")
        return

    await call.message.answer("weather.get_weather()")
    last_time = datetime.now()
```

Comment: А как вместо await message.answer("Слишком часто") сделать модальное окно, чтобы оно в чат не отправляло уже

Comment: Модальное окно можно сделать только через инлайн кнопку

Comment: То есть если вы вместо команды сделаете инлайн кнопку, обработаете ее в колбек хендлере и сделаете  практически тот-же код, то можно вот так await call.answer("Слишком часто")

Comment: А можна пример?

Comment: Обновил, пробуйте